# fullcalendar single slot event end time

Tags: events, time, fullcalendar

I am using fullcalendar in the agendaWeek view. I noticed that events that are in a single slot, lets say 30 min, do not display the endtime. The endtime only apears on events that cover more than one slot.
All the options that I've found did not add that to the event title.

Is that possible and I just didn't see it?
Thanks for any suggestions!

EDIT:
This is the Tool I am referring to.
http://fullcalendar.io/

Comment: Have you looked at the fullcalendar API? I am assuming you are talking about the Ruby gem??

Comment: Hi Matt, I didn't even notice that I missed that Info :) Thanks!
I added the the Link to the original Post

Comment: I have same issue ..Pls help me ... I have start time:10 : 30 am . but in week : it showing 10:30 to 12:30

Answer (score 4):

In the function `renderEventTable` there is a condition that adds a css class if the event is smaller than 30px.

```
if (seg.bottom - seg.top < 30) {
    seg.el.addClass('fc-short');
}
```

So basicly you can just edit the CSS style for `.fc-short`.

```
fc-time-grid-event.fc-short .fc-time span {
    display: none; /* don't display the full time text... */
}

.fc-time-grid-event.fc-short .fc-time:before {
    content: attr(data-start); /* ...instead, display only the start time */
}

.fc-time-grid-event.fc-short .fc-time:after {
    content: "\000A0-\000A0"; /* seperate with a dash, wrapped in nbsp's */
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I agree that just modifing the style where you need it makes more sense but @Abdullah provided only half the solution. Don't forget to clear the trailing - in the :after section of .fc-time

```
.fc-time-grid-event.fc-short .fc-time:before {
    /* in short mode, only data-start and data-full are available */
    content: attr(data-full);
}

.fc-time-grid-event.fc-short .fc-time:after {
    /* remove the trailing - after you change the content from data-start to data-full */
    content: "";
}

.fc-time-grid-event.fc-short .fc-title:before {
    content: "\00a0"; /* when a title exists along with the short time pad it with something like a nbsp*/
}
```

Answer (score 0):

An easy and better solution that worked around was to simply add css.
which will show [start time] - [end time] [title]

```
.fc-time-grid-event.fc-short .fc-time:before {
        content: attr(data-full); /* ...instead, display only the start time */
    }
```